# How do servers respond to TCP Keep Alive?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, tcp, redis, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to understand connectivity issues across node-redis and ioredis using Compose.io as a provider and Kue as the consuming client.

After a period of inactivity around 5 minutes, the next operation fails with a `ECONNRESET` error. I suspect this is because a proxy is closing the connection. I've tried setting the keepalive property on the Redis server itself to 15 seconds, but this behavior persists.

The application in question is deployed using Elastic Beanstalk. The load balancer is in a public subnet and the instance itself is in a private subnet and will only respond to the load balancer on Port 80. The private instance communicates with the internet via a [NAT Gateway](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/vpc-nat-gateway.html#nat-gateway-troubleshooting-timeout).

Could something with my setup be causing the application never respond to the keep alive requests, thus causing the connection to die?

Comment: TCP keepalive doesn't affect what a proxy does. The proxy isn't even aware of it. You need to look at the proxy's own configuration.